How to get all values from several tables by the key from the first one
I got 3 tables:



id
fruit




1
apple


2
banana



And two more:



id
frutId
type




1
1
grany


3
1
adam


1
1
golden


3
2
yeallow



and last one:



id
frutId
country




1
1
Europe


3
1
Asia


1
1
America


3
2
Latin



So I'm trying to get all values by matching id from the first table to the fruitId from others.
When I try to make the next query:
SELECT * FROM listing 
    JOIN listingCountry ON (listing.id=listingCountry.fruitId) 
GROUP BY listing.id`

(LEFT JOIN / UNITE - got the same results...)
I receive only the first lines from the table, like:
apple : grany : europe
And I need to get it like:
apple: grany, adam, golden : Europe, Asia, Americe
How can I form the query to get that results?

provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for this data, with the explanations.

Is the order of apple type and country in the published desired result important to you? Are the published IDs in tables 2 and 3 correct?

sorry. ids for the second and third tables not in a right order, but they're not matter. Order of apple type and country is also not matter.
The ket point is to get all values from 2 snd 3 tables that match first.id == second/third.fruitId

According to my understand, you want value from three tables like:
    apple  :   grany, adam, golden   :   Europe, Asia, Americe
    banana :   yeallow               :   Latin

So, use MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function to concatenate multiple rows into single field.
So, you query should be:
select 
    listing.fruit,
    T1.listingType_val,
    T2.listingCountry_val
from listing 
left join (
    select frutid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(type) as listingType_val
    from listingType
    group by frutid
) T1
on listing.id = T1.frutid
left join (
    select frutid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(country) as listingCountry_val
    from listingCountry
    group by frutid
) T2
on listing.id = T2.frutid


Check Live response: db<>fiddle

Yea!!! Thanks! It is the right what I needed!
