How to ignore Row was cut by GROUP_CONCAT error
I have a function that uses GROUP_CONCAT. On my local database if the function tries to concatenate more than the value of group_concat_max_len, it just gives me a string of that size, without throwing any errors. But the production database throws the error Row X was cut by GROUP_CONCAT().
Both databases are in the same version (8.0.36) and both are using the same sql_mode (STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION), both have the same engine (InnoDB).
I know I can increase the value of group_concat_max_len, but I want to know how the error could just be ignored in production, in the same way my local database does. Is there a configuration to ignore this error that I am missing?

This question is similar to: MySQL "Row 30153 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()" error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not an error, it is a warning....

What engine are you using? STRICT_TRANS_TABLES only affects transitional tables - if a non-transactional engine is used, STRICT_ALL_TABLES would become relevant.

Please share the current setting for this group_concat_max_len.

Here is a scenario (i) your local database uses MyISAM whereas production database uses InnoDB engine (ii) you're using group_concat in an insert or update query (iii) that query produces error for second or subsequent row. According to the manual, on non-transactional tables with strict_trans_table enabled and error on second or subsequent row there is only warning+truncation, no error. So it works on local but not on production.

It's returning as an error, not as warning.
The current group_concat_max_len is 8192

Both local e prod uses InnoDB.
The value is not inserted or updates a table/row

@Luuk the answer of that question just says to increase the value of group_concat_max_len. Which I have done previously, the problem was "resolved" until a different client had an even bigger set of values that needed concatenation. I can increase it even further but it becomes a problem increasing the value every time a client has more text

You need to share more details, because when do a query which CAN result in a group_concat with a max length above 8192, than, what do you expect ? So you should calculate max length of this, and then set these variable accordingly, or change the query, so the group_concat cannot result in such a long thing...

@Luuk I would expect that production would have the same result as my local database. If I try to concatenate with a max length above 8192 in production the database throws an error. On my local database it doesn't, the string is just kept at 8192 chars, but it does not throw an error.
What details are necessary that I haven't yet shared? I'd be happy to

Please try to share a [mre], (a max_length shorter than 8192 would do ) which shows the error, Because I only get warnings.  Also I would like to see what your local database has as a result when the string is larger than 8192 characters.  I think, at least one, of the variable values (SHOW VARIABLES) is different on production, when comparing to your local database.

@EliasLopesSalmoria Sample question to understand GROUP_CONCAT(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78875033/how-to-get-all-values-from-several-tables-by-the-key-from-the-first-one

Please be specific what do you mean by "throws an error". Which part of your code throws an error? What SQL query generates the error? Do you have exact same data in local vs production?
